# Как поменять только координату Х в консоли?

Tags: c, c++, консоль

Есть функция:

```
void SetPos(int x, int y)
    {
        HANDLE h=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
        COORD C; //Описываем переменную для задания координат.
        C.X=x;
        C.Y=y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(h,C);
    }
```

Как поменять, только координату Х, а У оставить как и должна быть, если запустить консоль?

Если убрать 2ой параметр в функции и строчку "C.Y=y;", то функция менять положение координаты не будет.

Comment: Читаем описание [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), на которое есть ссылка из [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и легко находим текущие координаты курсора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void  CursorPosX(HANDLE hout, SHORT x) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hout, &info);

    info.dwCursorPosition.X = x;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hout, info.dwCursorPosition);
}

//...

HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
CursorPosX(h, 20);
```